# Show regional characters in MessageBox without setting required locale

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, character-encoding

I need to show `MessageBox` with regional characters described in `ISO/IEC 8859-13` codepage without setting Windows locale to this region. I was naive and tried to show ASCI table with one byte character:

```
void showCodePage()
{


    char *a = new char[10000];
    char *aa = new char[10000];
    int f=0;
    int lines =0;
    for (int i=1; i<255;i++ )
    {
        sprintf(a,"%c %0.3d ",i,i);
        sprintf(aa,"%c",i);
        f++;
        a+=6;
        aa++;

        if (f==8)
        {
            f=0;
            sprintf(a,"%c",0x0d);
            a++;
            lines++;
        }

    }

    *aa=0;
    *a=0;
    a-=254*6+lines;
    aa-=254;


    MessageBox(NULL, aa , "Hello!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    MessageBox(NULL, a  , "Hello!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

    delete [] a;
    delete [] aa;

}
```

Ok, this doesn't shows ISO/IEC 8859-13 correctly and this is not possible without changing locale:

[image]

Now I decide to make unicode wstring. Converting from single byte char to unicode wchar function:

```
wstring convert( const std::string& as )
{
    // deal with trivial case of empty string
    if( as.empty() )    return std::wstring();

    // determine required length of new string
    size_t reqLength = ::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, as.c_str(), (int)as.length(), 0, 0 );

    // construct new string of required length
    std::wstring ret( reqLength, L'\0' );

    // convert old string to new string
    ::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, as.c_str(), (int)as.length(), &ret[0], (int)ret.length() );

    // return new string ( compiler should optimize this away )
    return ret;
}
```

And changing MessageBox'es:

```
MessageBoxW(NULL, convert(aa).c_str(), L"Hello!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
MessageBoxW(NULL, convert(a).c_str() , L"Hello!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

Result is still sad:

[image]

In other hand what I was expecting? I need somehow tell system which code page it should use to display may characters. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that the function `MultiByteToWideChar` with `CodePage` parameter `CP_UTF8` deosn't translate your SPECIFIC `ASCII` code-page to `UTF-16`, it translates `UTF-8` to `UTF-16`, which is not what you need.

What you're looking for is a translation table from chars in `ISO/IEC 8859-13` to `WideChar`. You can manually make one from the table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-13, e.g. `160` becomes `00A0`, `161` to `201D`, and so on.